# Merge Duplicate values in drop down php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to merge duplicate values that i have in my drop down list, i dont want to use `array_unique` because it deletes my second duplicate value. The way my program works is if you select a location it will populate my second drop down accordingly. [image]

If you look at the picture provided you can see two duplicate entries `Rosebank` when i click the first rosebank it will only show me on provider in my second drop down but when i click on the second rosebank it shows me all the providers with the location `rosebank`. I would like to know if there is a way i can merge the two duplicates so that it will show me all the providers when i click `rosebank` and it should only show one `rosebank`.

Here is my code without `array_unique`:

```
    <label for="select-service">
                <strong>Enter a Location:</strong>
            </label>
            <select class="form-control" id="select-location" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 form-control" required>
                <option value="">Select Location</option>



                 <?php


            foreach($appointment_locations as $location) {



             $LocationsArray = explode(",", $location->notes);

              foreach($LocationsArray as $singleLocation):
                 ?>

                <option value="<?=$singleLocation ?>"><?=$singleLocation  ?></option>                  

                <? endforeach;

                 };?>

            </select>
```

and here is what i have tried with `array_unique`, it successfully deletes the duplicates but as i said earlier, it will only show me one value in my next drop down and not all

```
  <label for="select-service">
                <strong>Enter a Location:</strong>
            </label>
            <select class="form-control" id="select-location" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 form-control" required>
                <option value="">Select Location</option>



                 <?php

          foreach(array_unique($appointment_locations) as $location) {
           // foreach($appointment_locations as $location) {



             $LocationsArray = explode(",", $location->notes);

              foreach($LocationsArray as $singleLocation):
                 ?>

                <option value="<?=$singleLocation ?>"><?=$singleLocation  ?></option>                  

                <? endforeach;

                 };?>

            </select>
```

here is my `var_dump`

```
                         array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#28 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["notes"]=>
    string(29) "Randburg, Greenside, Rosebank"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#29 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["notes"]=>
    string(8) "Rosebank"
  }
}
```

Comment: try to do `var_dump($appointment_locations);` and let us know what exactly $appointment_locations contains in it.

Comment: I do not understand: you want to merge values but not merge keys? it seems unlogic

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro I want to merge the keys too

Comment: @Akhilesh I have updated and showed the dump

Comment: There is something strange in the $appointment_locations. It seems Randburg, Greenside and Rosebank do have same id.

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro Because it is stored like that in the database, just separated by a comma

Comment: i still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. You have Rosebank twice with 2 different ids. It seems impossible to get what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

Get the unique locations by storing them in an array as the keys:

```
$unique_locations = [];
foreach(array_unique($appointment_locations) as $location) {
    foreach(explode(",", $location->notes) as $singleLocation) {
        $unique_locations[$singleLocation] = 1;
    }
}
?>
```

Use array_keys, array_map and implode to put it all together:

```
...
<select>
    <?= implode('', array_map(function($location) { return "<option value='$location'>$location</option>"; }, array_keys($unique_locations)))  ?>
</select>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model file use $this-db->group_by(' colum name ');